# Post does not work

Tags: php, zurb-foundation

I have a really annoying problem.

I have a form and when I Submit it it doesn't set the post.

```
<form action="pages/post-reply" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Comment on admin"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="tiny button" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

I use a framework called [Processwire](http://processwire.com/) and Foundation but I don't think this has anything to do with it.

When I try it out on my webserver (a dedicated host) it works. I am using a WAMP install on Windows 8. Could this have anything to do with it?

When I use:

```
    echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

It just says:

> GET

Edit: .htaccess file:

### http://textdump.net/raw/2212/

Still not any progress, does anyone know if it might be Wamp or Windows 8 screwing this up?

Comment: i can guess your htaccess url rewriting may cause the trouble. navigating to "pages/post-reply" does work?

Comment: check that your 'pages/post-reply` page isn't being redirected when you submit the form.

Comment: and that pages/post-reply is the actual path you want relative to this file. You sure you're hitting the right page?

Comment: It works. since the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by redirection either from the page of `pages/post-reply` itself or  `.htaccess` rule on the root directory who is redirecting the request `pages/post-reply` as a GET Request.

Check your `.htaccess` rule

According to your .htaccess file, this is the line that is redirecting your request to a different URL

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, modifying this rule will probably crack your application, so basically what happens is the request gets send to the script as

```
index.php?it=pages/post-reply
```

So may be this is help you solve further.

Comment: I've edited my post with the ROOT HTACCESS file. I can't really find anything that might caus this problem but I am not an expert if it comes to HTACCESS and certainly not when someone else wrote it.

Comment: @Hawiak Try it by removing or commenting out your `.htaccess` file, see what that gives. And if you have any error outputs, post them.

Comment: The strange thing is that it works, the exact same code on a domain, or an other server... I have no idea where to look in my configuration files... Thanks for your time though, much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but the right answer might just benefit someone. The first line should read.

```
<form action="<?php echo $config->urls->templates ?>pages/post-reply" method="post">
```

See http://cheatsheet.processwire.com/ for details.